# What is the meaning of the a(ss) type in the dconf, and what are the correct methods of gi.repository.Gio.Settings to get/set such fields?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, gnome

On Gnome I have been playing around with the dconf. I am trying to write some Python scripts to manipulate some of the entries myself. Some of them have the type `a(ss)`. So my first question is: what does this type mean?

I'm handling the dconf thus:

```
from gi.repository import Gio
entries = Gio.Settings.new(path)
value1 = entries.get_string(key1) # for reading a string value
entries.set_string(key2, value2)  # for writing a string value
```

This works fine, until I try to work with a key whose type is `a(ss)`. The methods `get_string()` and `set_string()` fail because of a wrong type. So my second question is: what are the right methods to use in this case?

I am using Python 3.4.2 on Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: I have meantime discovered that `a(ss)` means an array of 2-tuples of strings ( https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GVariantType.html ); the question of how to read/write such entities with the Gio.Settings object still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my searches haven't revealed anything, but by playing around with the various methods I've managed to come up with a solution:

```
from gi.overrides import GLib
value1 = entries.get_value(key1).unpack() # returns e.g. [("a", "b"), ("c", "d")]
entries.set_value(key2, GLib.Variant("a(ss)", value2)) # value2 is e.g. [("a", "b"), ("c", "d")]
```

As this is merely a (working) piece of code I've managed to come up with myself, without completely understanding what's going on, I will wait for some time to see if someone can shed some more light on the issue and/or offer a neater solution (or at least reassure me that I've done it right) before accepting my own answer.

Comment: You have been doing well. You are dealing with the textual representation of GVariant. You have possibly missed https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/gvariant-text.html#gvariant-text-arrays and https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/gvariant-format-strings.html which explains it a bit more.